# CSS ::after border issue

Tags: html, css

Hope you all doing very good. Here i am facing an issue related to ::after in css, please find the code details at below....

```css
.Product__sizes__tooltiptext {
      display: none;
    }
.Product__sizes__button {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        color: #333;
        display: block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 42px;
        height: 42px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 42px;
  }

        // disabled buttons
      .Product__sizes__tooltiptext{
            display: none;
            height: 28px;
            line-height: 28px;
            background-color: #f1f1ef;
            color: #000;
            width: 180px;
            border: 1px solid #808285;
            padding: 0px 2px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            margin-top: -80px;
            margin-left: -70px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.3s;
            font-size: 14px;
  }
  .Product__sizes__tooltiptext::after {
   content: "";
              position: absolute;
              top: 100%;
              left: 50%;
              margin-left: -9px;
              border-left: 8px solid #808285;
              border-right: 8px solid #808285;
              border-top: 7px solid #f1f1ef;
  }
.Product__sizes__tooltip:hover .Product__sizes__tooltiptext{
   display: block;
            opacity: 1;
  }
      .Product__sizes__tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="Product__sizes__button  Product__sizes__tooltip disabled">
                      6.5<span class="Product__sizes__tooltiptext">Not available in selected size</span>
                    </a>
```

Here i want to remove extra border-color added in on ::after of tooltip tag. Please let me know if anything more need more from my side. Thanks in advance!!!

Just wanted to removed black ::after border should be look like this as its showing below image

[image]

Comment: Hi @BanshiLalDangi please find the code link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPgywB

Comment: Does your code look like this in your text editor? Why wouldn't you at least format it correctly before wondering why it doesn't work?

Comment: Actually if you will see my code .. i just want change in ::after border only .. and my ::after border should look like as per image....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the look in the image, you need to use `:before` and `:after` laid on top of each other. Your code needed to add a little more than just an after tag to get the effect you're looking for.

Might be worth looking at a tooltip generator like [this](https://www.cssportal.com/css-tooltip-generator/) to help you in future.

For now, I have amended your code to what the image looks like:

```css
.Product__sizes__button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 42px;
}

a.Product__sizes__tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
}

a.Product__sizes__tooltip .Product__sizes__tooltiptext {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border: 2px solid #6D6D6D;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a.Product__sizes__tooltip .Product__sizes__tooltiptext:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 12px solid #6D6D6D;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
}

a.Product__sizes__tooltip .Product__sizes__tooltiptext:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #F2F2F2;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

a:hover.Product__sizes__tooltip .Product__sizes__tooltiptext {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 52px;
  left: -200%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tooltips Product__sizes__button Product__sizes__tooltip disabled">6.5
<span class="Product__sizes__tooltiptext">Not available in selected size</span></a>
```

Comment: @STiwari Your code looks nothing like the picture that you have now added. However, I have amended my answer to include a few more features for you. Take a look. Does this help you at all?

Comment: @STiwari Did this help you?

Comment: yes this solve my issue, but i want this to be defer as per button size, can you please help on this?

Comment: Sorry @STiwari - I dont understand your question?

Comment: suppose some button text is more like 'W Wide Custom', 'W Custom' then how i will display tooltip as in center as per button width... is this is clear?

Answer (score 0):

You just set the border property inside .Product__sizes__button {} from solid to none. It will remove the border around it.

```css
.Product__sizes__tooltiptext {
  display: none;
}

.Product__sizes__button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px none #333;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 42px;
}

.Product__sizes__button.disabled .Product__sizes__tooltiptext {
  display: none;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background-color: #f1f1ef;
  color: #000;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #808285;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.Product__sizes__button.disabled .Product__sizes__tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  border-left: 8px solid #808285;
  border-right: 8px solid #808285;
  border-top: 7px solid #f1f1ef;
}

.Product__sizes__button.disabled:hover .Product__sizes__tooltiptext {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.Product__sizes__tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="Product__sizes__button  Product__sizes__tooltip disabled">
                      6.5<span class="Product__sizes__tooltiptext">Not available in selected size</span>
                    </a>
```

Comment: Hi please find the link of code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPgywB , as per this code i just wanted to remove ::after border...